# Why does save.saves on the Graph API return a null value?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On trying to use Facebook's Graph API explorer to view saved links, as suggested by many answers before, I tried to run a 
`GET /v2.4/me/save.saves` with all permissions granted. It returns this however:

`{"data": [  ] }`

I've also noticed that a number of people with a similar question have been asked to run save.saves and have received a null result post which there has been no resolution thus leading to this roadblock.

Comment: It seems that this endpoint is actually not supported and is documented by error.